# How to create dynamic title that changes on filter in Markdown using Handlebars (mustache)?

Tags: markdown, handlebars.js, visualization, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am currently using OpenSearch visualization, type TVSB. I have a title ex: Motors Limited in the markdown section. I want the title to be changed every time when I apply a filter to the dashboards. This visualization is a part of the dashboards. For example: filter is organization.name is Jon Jones. Then the title should change to Jon Jones. I would like to automate the process.

Please suggest any solution or advice how to solve it.

Thank you

I was thinking about adding JS inside the markdown but did not work, err: use Markdown and Handlebars only. Also, I was thinking maybe I somehow should apply Dev Tool section of the opensearch but not familiar with it.